# Remote Chrome WebDriver on gcp

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-cloud-platform, webdriver, remotewebdriver

I run remote chrome webdriver in GCP Cloud Run. It works well if I use unathenicated service call and i can connect from my java code to this Chrome Webdriver. However, once i [enable gcp authentication service-to-service](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service), it stops working. I wasn't able to find a way to provide google token to Selenium Remote Webdriver. I understand that I need to extend one of existing Selenium java classes, like RemoteWebDriver or HttpCommandExecutor, but it's not clear which class exactly. Please advice.